# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined Graph API[2.5]

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook Graph API to make 2 API calls. The 1st API call returns the list of friends using the same web app and the 2nd API call returns the public info of the logged in user. I'm facing a problem inside the ***for loop*** of the function containing the 1st API call. Whenever I try to read the data in the response I'm getting an error..

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

**My JavaScript SDK Code**..

```
        function facebookSignIn() {

        FB.login(function(response) {
            // handle the response
            console.log("Response goes here!");

            // retrieve the list of friends to whom message was sent
            FB.api(
                '/me/friends', function (response) {
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        console.log("Response for /me/friends goes here!");
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data[0].name));
                        for(var i =0;i<=response.data.length;i++){
                            var friend_name = response.data[i].name;
                            var friend_id= response.data[i].id+"@fb";                       
                            addFriendSetValues(friend_name, '-', friend_id, loginemail);
                            addFriendDbCreate();
                        }
                    }
                }
            );

            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,locale,gender', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name+" "+response.id+" "+response.email);
                loginpassword = response.id;
                loginemail =  response.email;

                loginDbCreate();    //this function is in the script_admin_v2.js
            });

        }, {scope: 'email,public_profile,user_friends'});            
    }
```

**Console Output**..

```
    Response for /me/friends goes here!
    [{"name":"Friend A","id":"10153492155956028"},{"name":"Friend B","id":"117431545310469"}]
   "Friend A"
    Successful login for: Lucy 951425764944314 lucy@abc.com
    all.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Even though I'm able to print the value of *response.data[0].name)*, when I replace the zero with i ***inside the for loop***, I get the Uncaught Error..Any idea where I'm going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need change

```
for(var i =0;i<=response.data.length;i++){
      var friend_name = response.data[i].name;
      var friend_id= response.data[i].id+"@fb";
      addFriendSetValues(friend_name, '-', friend_id, loginemail);
      addFriendDbCreate();
 }
```

to

```
 for(var i =0;i<=response.data.length;i++){
      if (response.data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var friend_name = response.data[i].name;
        var friend_id = response.data[i].id + "@fb";
        addFriendSetValues(friend_name, '-', friend_id, loginemail);
        addFriendDbCreate();
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm facing problem with the statement inside the for loop.